# Sony ZR5 Audio Control API

Tags: sony-audio-control-api

How i can send to my Sony ZR5 audio stream like http://air.radiorecord.ru:805/chil_320 using api?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As this device have build-in chromecast engine, you can too use it to stream url. ATM I m using python with this code.

```
import time
import pychromecast

name = ''

chromecasts = pychromecast.get_chromecasts()
for cc in chromecasts:
    print (cc.device.friendly_name)
    name = cc.device.friendly_name

cast = next(cc for cc in chromecasts if cc.device.friendly_name == name)
cast.wait()
print(cast.device)
print(cast.status)

mc = cast.media_controller
mc.play_media('https://c1icy.prod.playlists.ihrhls.com/7053_icy', 'audio/mp3')
mc.block_until_active()
print(mc.status)

mc.pause()
time.sleep(5)
mc.play()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your only option is to use DLNA, and it will not work for all streams.
I have had best success then using IP number and not the hostname.

Comment: I used the server on the linux Mkchromecast to transfer the audio stream from the Internet radio to the ZR5.